# ExtLib Mobile Controls - How to build a button to switch to an appPage

Tags: xpages

I'm working on an XPage for mobile users for an existing application. I want to use the mobile controls from the ExtLib for this.

I've build an XPage with a SinglePageApp and some AppPages on it. Now I want to build an AppPage with a search menu, a simple inputText and a button to start the search.

The inputText is bind to a sessionScope variable. I want to use the variable in a second appPage to get the search value and show a filtered/searched view.

The problem is the button. I'm not sure how to build this button to move to the other appPage. This is my last attempt, which fails with a runtime error.

Any idea how to get this running or what's wrong ?

Kind regards
Ingo

```
<xe:appPage id="appPage34" pageName="searchPage" preload="true" resetContent="true">
        <xe:djxmHeading id="djxmHeading34" label="Search..." back="Home" moveTo="home">
        </xe:djxmHeading>
        <xp:inputText id="searchInput" value="#{sessionScope.searchValue}">
        </xp:inputText>
        <xp:button value="Search" id="button1" refreshMode="complete" type="submit">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true">
                <xp:this.action>
                    <xe:moveTo targetPage="#searchResult"></xe:moveTo>
                </xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
    </xe:appPage>
```

Comment: can't you just do context.redirectToPage("anotherpag")?

Comment: I can give it a try but as I understood the construct of the single app page / app pages, you have to use a moveTo because you stay on the same XPage and simply switch to a certain part of this XPage.

Comment: As I thought : redirectToPage isn't working in this context because I don't want to open another XPage, but stay on the same XPage and switch to another appPage (Mobile Page).

Answer (score 0):

What does the runtime error say?

If you can not get to the XPages log files on the server directly, then use [XPages Log File Reader from OpenNTF](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?name=XPages%20Log%20File%20Reader) to get easy access to the log files from a browser.

Does it work if you use "searchResult" as the value for `targetPage` (assuming the appPage is called "searchResult")?

Comment: searchResult is not working as targetPage. Same error. Error message is "unexpected runtime error" (think so, error message is in german). No further information in the error. I will checkt the log files.

Comment: This is what happens in the XPages log :  20.09.12 11:41: Exception Thrown
Context Path: /test/vvappmob.nsf
Page Name: /mHome_1.xsp
javax.faces.FacesException
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:250)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:223)
at

Comment: at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:200)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:137)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1267)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:847

Comment: at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1251)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:598)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:421)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)

Comment: at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1151)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:302)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:222)at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:899)
at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.actions.MoveToAction.setParentPageID(MoveToAction.java:217)

Comment: at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.actions.MoveToAction.invoke(MoveToAction.java:198)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:60)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:324)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIEventHandler.broadcast(UIEventHandler.java:366)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.broadcast(UIViewRootEx.java:1535)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:307)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:428)

Comment: at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:94)
... 19 more  
  Sorry for the many comments. Didn't know how to post the log.

Answer (score 0):

I've now come to a solution with a static line item instead of a button, since I couldn't get the button working. I think it has something to do with the way the single page application handles the access to mobile pages.

The search page looks like this :

```
<xe:appPage id="appPage34" pageName="searchPage" preload="true" resetContent="true">
        <xe:djxmHeading id="djxmHeading34" label="Search..." back="Home" moveTo="home">
        </xe:djxmHeading>
        <xp:inputText id="searchInput" value="#{sessionScope.searchValue}">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onblur" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
                <xp:this.action>
                    <xp:executeScript>
                        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:var svalue = getComponent("searchInput").getValue(); sessionScope.put("searchValue",svalue);}]]></xp:this.script>
                    </xp:executeScript>
                </xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:inputText>
        <xp:br></xp:br>
        <xp:br></xp:br>
        <xe:djxmLineItem id="djxmLineItem41" label="Start Search..." moveTo="#searchResult">
        </xe:djxmLineItem>
    </xe:appPage>
```

In the mobile page for showing the search result I simply get the value of the sessionScope variable, issue a full text search with the value and use the resulting document collection in a repeat control.

I still would rather use a button because the static line item is not really what a user expects as a gui element to start the search. But at least this is working.